# jpa many to many with additional column and composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 tables :folder(simple primary key) and document(composite primary key)
I want a join table named folder_documents which will contains the id of both tables with additional columns

There is my entities:

Folder

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "folder")

public class Folder {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "folder_seq_gen", sequenceName = "FOLDER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "folder_seq_gen")
    private long id;

    @Column
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "folder_documents_compositeKey.folder",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Folder_Documents> folder_documents;
```

Document

```
@Entity
@Table(name="document")
public class Document {

    @EmbeddedId 
    private DocumentID documentCompositeKey;

    @Column
    private Date date;
```

DocumentID(composite key)

```
@Embeddable
public class DocumentID implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String id;
    private String matricule;
```

Folder_Document ( join table)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "folder_documents")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "folder_documents_compositeKey.folder",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "folder_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "folder_documents_compositeKey.document",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id" , referencedColumnName = "id")), // error mapping there
    @AssociationOverride(name = "folder_documents_compositeKey.document",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "matricule" , referencedColumnName = "matricule"))})// error mapping there
public class Folder_Documents {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Folder_Documents_ID folder_documents_compositeKey  = new Folder_Documents_ID();

    @Column
    private Date date;

    @Column
    private String status;
```

Folder_documents_id(composite key)

```
@Embeddable
public class Folder_Documents_ID implements Serializable { 

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Folder folder;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Document document;
```

The problem is i can't map the `Document` compositeKey in `Folder_Documents`' s `@AssociationOverrides` attributes because hibernate don't find the composite key id and matricule properties in `Document` . Folder references is fine .

There is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(matricule) of com.renault.entity.Folder_Documents_ID.folder_documents_compositeKey.document referencing com.renault.entity.Document not mapped to a single property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved , the syntax of the AssociationOverride annotation was wrong

Correct syntax :

```
AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "folder_documents_compositeKey.folder", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "folder_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "folder_documents_compositeKey.document",  joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id" , referencedColumnName = "id") ,
            @JoinColumn(name = "matricule" , referencedColumnName = "matricule") })})
```